# Facebook API: How can i get mutual friends sharing a same link in wall?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I develop an application which can list mutual friends who share same links like me. 
Ex: I share a link: http://example.com over my application.
Friend A, Friend B, Friend C share this link too.
Matter is how can I know Friend A, Friend B share link "http://example.com".

Comment: That's not possible via the Graph API.

Answer (score 1):

If everything gets shared via your App, you can just store the shared link in your own Database - with the User ID of the User who shared it. After that it should be easy to compare.

Comment: Thanks! Is that exactly that fb's not support us to access information in this case :), of course We can use this way

Comment: yeah, there is no way to do this with the api. after all it´s faster for you anyway, api calls take a bit longer than just doing a quick select in your own database.